# Can we infer generic typed parameter from function's parameter?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So code looks like something like this:

```
enum Status {
  Open = "open",
  Closed = "closed"
}

interface DefaultRequest {
  status: Status
}

interface OpenRequest extends DefaultRequest {
  status: Status.Open;
  data?: Record<string, Status.Open>
}

interface CloseRequest extends DefaultRequest {
  status: Status.Close;
  data?: Record<string, Status.Close>
}

interface MapRequest {
  [Status.Open]: OpenRequest;
  [Status.Close]: CloseRequest;
}

type Request = OpenRequest | CloseRequest;

function isValidRequestType<T extends Status> (data: Request): T is MapRequest[T] {
  return true;
}

isValidRequest<Status.Open>({ status: Status.Open }) //passed argument is typecasted to OpenRequest
isValidRequest({ status: Status.Open }) // passed argument is typecasted to Request
```

Is it possible that if I don't pass the generic parameter at function call and isValidRequest can still infer the status from the passed argument's attribute (aka status)?

Something like

```
function isValidRequestType<T extends Status> (data: Request & {type: T}): T is MapRequest[T] {
  return true;
}
isValidRequest({ status: Status.Open }) // passed argument is OpenRequest??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but I think you want something like:

```
function isValidRequestType<T extends Status>(
  data: Request & { status: T }
): data is Request & { status: T } {
  return true;
}
```

When you do `data is Request & { status: T }` you are saying the argument named `data` is the union `Request` with only the members that match `{ status: T }`. This narrows that union to only the options that have that status.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=20&ssc=11&pln=20&pc=21#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgeQAdQoBeKAIgHtiQKAaHPAYQBsqVgATMygY3acuFHAF8cOAJYg4wAE4AzBH2BQAIsCVhWcAErAAjmGAo4GJlFNJUALliJkKMROzTZi5aqKh9Rk2eAAD1kQLjQNLR1fY1NzXEsHW3trFAA6bxAAbgsuJAQAfjt9Pio5LgAeUzlpAHN6ZMd02gA+Z2wpGXklFSg2DmBo-yggkLD1TQRtPUMYsyx4q0c7eBTUvqFs+NzEQqhi0oqq2vqVxvXuVuxxdtdOjx6AWQRCQdj5vABtU9Qm0ABdOwZV5wTafb5pc5cAG9QQDGb+TbXHBwACexCgDxRwN4QPhsQAPjD+sDNjgFGAQHw4JIqCAoJIUAA1BCsSRcYEAFTRwHKHOGwVAY3BzQAFDk8nZMdiAGQYBIpOx864ASjs2wQ9LQUrxZll6HlSygSrieDkwGQcjpcDkxkRLgZzNZ7J1XOI5XBvxAov1iySHoyUFEyqgAHoQ4QECghFAEHIapBQGYGVBUcQ+JHZDw4FQCLRgVImSy2ZzuSKfYkUMsK57A8Gw1AI1HuDG4wmZJqU9z06Zm9m9jqgA)